# Jquery and colorbox - No exit button?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Finally I've got colorbox working fine.

BUT it's not showing any buttons?

Look here:
http://www.logo-fabrikken.dk

Try press "kontakt" in the right menu to see my problem with Colorbox

Regards, Nikolai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resources location for the `ColorBox`'s resources is being wrongly resolved.

Either,

- Place `colorbox.css` in the root directory. i.e. outside of the `popup` folder, next to your `style.css` file.
- Or, change the resources' location inside your `colorbox.css` file. e.g.

  ```
  background:url(popup/images/controls.png)
  ```

  should become

  ```
  background:url(images/controls.png)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

upload `controls.png`, you haven't uploaded the image in images folder. Try to open your url in chrome and inspect it, it will show you missing resources.

Comment: Also loading.gif was missing underneath Kontakt and staravenue.ttf